# blank page or runtime error when serving page after handling form submission

Tags: go, web-frameworks

I am able to load a html page ( index.html ) who's `<body></body>` contents looks like the following:

```
<form action="ask" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>
```

What I am trying to so is render index.html and then on submission of the ask render a copy of index.html except have some of the contents come from my golang code as a results page.

When I submit the form in index.html, I get a blank page.

But I am getting no data received when going to localhost:8000/view or
localhost:8000/view?q=hello+world in the browser. And in the terminal, I get this and a lot more, but this is the first line:

**http: panic serving [::1]:53803: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference**

what does it mean and how can I fix it?

WhenI go to /ask or /ask?q=hello+world, which is what I am trying to do, I get the blank page with no errors.

I am trying to handle ask on the initial page that is loaded and on the results page once that ask form has been submitted.

index.html, view.html, and edit.html all have this:

```
<form method="get" action="ask">

    <input type="text" name="q" />

</form>
```

Here is my code now:

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"

    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Page struct {

    Title string

    Body []byte

}

func (p *Page) save() error{

    filename := p.Title + ".txt"

    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600) 

}

func loadPage(title string) (*Page, error){

    filename := title + ".txt"

    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)

    if err != nil{

        return nil, err

    }

    return &Page{Title: title, Body: body}, nil 

}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, p *Page){

    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl + ".html")

    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    t.Execute(w, p)

}

func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    //title := r.URL.Path[len("/view/"):]

    title := r.FormValue("q")

    p, err := loadPage(title)

    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    renderTemplate(w, "view", p)

}

func editHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    //title := r.URL.Path[len("/edit/"):]

    title := r.FormValue("q")

    p, err := loadPage(title)

    if err != nil{

        p = &Page{Title: title}
        fmt.Println(err)

    }

    renderTemplate(w, "edit", p)

}

func response(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

}

func serveSingle(filename string) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        http.ServeFile(w, r, filename)

    }

}

func main() {

    goji.Get("/", serveSingle("Projects/Go/src/web/site/index.html"))

    goji.Handle("/ask", response)

    http.HandleFunc("/view/", viewHandler)

    http.HandleFunc("/edit/", editHandler)

    goji.Serve()

}
```

So I want to handle ask from the index.html and the results page and run response, which will render the results page on submission of the ask form from index.html and the results page.

Comment: Please add proper error handling to your code. You're suppressing error checking for the template parsing and execution.

Comment: @fls0815 I was doing that, just removed it when posting. I'm not getting any errors or anything printed in the terminal.

Comment: @fls0815 I ran it again and the only error I am getting is the one mentioned in my question.

Comment: Please stop the execution of all your functions (i. e. return or panic) when an error occurs. It's very likely that your error results of an ongoing execution of your code. And don't remove error handling; you *must* always check any error. Instead of only printing all error messages out, let them panic for debugging reasons (or at least return after printing them). You're missing a lot of proper error handling.

Comment: @fls0815 so I just do `return err` or `if err != nil{ return }`? Which one?

Comment: In `renderTemplate`, do a `panic(err)` and check the return value of `t.Execute()`. In `viewHandler` do a `panic(err)` as well. Same in `editHandler`, do a `panic(err)`. I wonder why there is a `save()` function because you never use it in your quoted code.

Comment: @fls0815 save() is a function from the tutorial I looked at to write this. I am not using it as they never did. In main() they had the call commented out.

Okay, now I am getting an error: open .txt: no such file or directory

Comment: @fls0815 I had it looking for a .txt when it was supposed to look for .html and proper error handling solve that thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proper error handling and you should see what is going on. For some reason it is either loading a blank file or no able to find the file and that is why the results page is blank.

As mentioned in the comments:

In renderTemplate, do a `panic(err)` and check the return value of `t.Execute()`. In viewHandler do a `panic(err)` as well. Same in editHandler, do a `panic(err)`.

See what those panics say and go from there.

Comment: Better is to use `log.Fatal(err)`, since you won't have to deal (esp. as a newbie) understanding the stack trace.